# Xamarin Essentials Web Authenticator & Open Browser

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials

For reference:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/open-browser?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?context=xamarin%2Fandroid&tabs=android

I am using both of these features and everything works as expected when I was on an emulator that targeted android 11. It was working without adding the recommended configurations from the documentation above.

when the app is run on an emulator that targets android 13, neither of these features works anymore.  the browser just opens and never finished loading the page.  If the browser is closed the app will recognize a cancel method was called.

from the documentation, I have tried with and without the configurations and to no avail.

```
<queries>
        <intent>
        <action android:name="android.support.customtabs.action.CustomTabsService" />
    </intent>
        <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="http"/>
  </intent>
  <intent>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="https"/>
  </intent>
    </queries>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: I tested the code official doc provided and ran it on both 11 and 13. As you said that the browser just opens and never finished loading the page. You can raise this issue to GitHub.

Comment: here is bug link on github https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/issues/2070

Comment: Well, you can follow up it.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I meant, by sharing the link.  I will follow up but also for anybody looking for the conversation.